# Running shell script to open two terminals and run commands in them

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm setting up a repo and I want to make a shell script that will run two commands that run a backend and build a frontend. What I have so far is something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sh -e "sh -c 'cd frontend && ng build'"
sh -e "sh -c 'cd backend && symfony server:start'"
```

When I try running that though, I get back `sh: 0: Can't open sh -c ...` for both lines. What is the solution to this? It should be clear that both these commands will not terminate until you do by hand. It is not necessary to open a new terminal for both commands, one can be executed in the current terminal.

Comment: Is a shell script *required*, or are you open to other solutions? There are many advantages to starting and monitoring services (including daemons) using systemd instead of a shell script.

Comment: @user535733 I'd like to have it a shell script, since I want to put it in a repo for people who aren't oriented in the application yet. They'd just be able to run this script and the work would be done for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be simplified:

```
$ ./twocmds.sh 
frontend
backend
$ cat ./twocmds.sh 
#!/bin/sh
/bin/sh -ec 'cd frontend && echo frontend'
/bin/sh -ec 'cd backend && echo backend'
```

Also, try to specify full paths in scripts. `frontend` and `backend` folders I've created in current directory, but it is better to specify full path to them.

It's an example output, because of I do not have your services. You should change `echo frontend` and `echo backend` by your commands, that means by `/usr/bin/ng build` and `/usr/bin/symfony server:start`. But before it do `whereis ng && whereis symfony` to find out full path to your commands.

Your script could look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
    /bin/sh -ec 'cd frontend && /usr/bin/ng build &'
    /bin/sh -ec 'cd backend && /usr/bin/symfony server:start'
```

Firstly try to use without `&`. But if the second command waits for the first command execution, then use `&` to send the first command into background. Also, if you need waiting before some commands execution, use `sllep X`, where `X` number of seconds.

Comment: I don't see what this accomplishes, as I specified the commands that I'm trying to run do not terminate, and from the script you provided I only get back `frontend\nbackend`.

Comment: Try updated answer

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

a=/absolute/path/frontend
b=/absolute/path/backend

if [[ ! -d $a ]] || [[ ! -d $b ]]; then
   echo "panic! path not found"
   exit 1
fi

cd $a
ng build

cd $b
symfony server:start
```

Comment: `ng build` doesn't terminate on its own (I've added `--watch`, but didn't feel like I'd have to add that in the question since I specified the commands wouldn't terminate on their own), and therefore this script doesn't get further than that command.

Comment: you are thinking of something like this: ```x-terminal-emulator -e "/bin/bash -c 'ls; exec bash'" &``` (exec bash isnt necessary if you dont intend to keep the terminal open after command has executed)